# What does cost mean in context of time complexity?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, data-science

Consider the following pseudo code:

```
Pseudocode:
list_Sum(A,n){//A->array and n->number of elements in the array
sum =0           // cost=1  no of times=1
for i=0 to n-1     // cost=2  no of times=n+1 (+1 for the end false condition)
sum = sum + A[i]   // cost=2  no of times=n 
return sum         // cost=1  no of times=1
}
```

What does cost mean in context of time complexity?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: 1. different optimization will end up with corresponding different assembler language, and the processes will different from the steps in your code. 2. Each process cost different time comsuming. An airthmetic step is pretty fast, and a fetch of data A[i] costs much loger time. The only practical way is counting the total execution time duration.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, actually. Theoretically, this would be the number of instructions required on a fictional architecture made up by the author. Practically, it doesn't map to any existing, relevant architecture. No real architecture has exactly these costs.

The only relevant part is the `times 1` or `times n` part, as that is applicable regardless of architecture.

There is also vectorization and super-scalarity, which easily slice the cost of e.g. the loop by factor 15-50 (so imagine that as a "real" cost of 0.02 for the body of the loop), but even then it stays `times n`.